# Unexpected results converting TIdBytes to Integer using BytesToInt64()

Tags: indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am reading UDP packets using the `TIdUDPServer.OnUDPRead` event.  Embedded in each packet is an 8-byte `QUint64`, which represents a radio frequency.  I am trying to read that frequency.

All attempts using `BytesToInt64()` are resulting in erroneous results.  I have verified the data is correct by reading the hex values with Wireshark and using a web-based hex-to-decimal converter.

I know the frequency in the packet data starts at position 23 and is 8 bytes long.

```
procedure TWSJTxUDPClient.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread:  TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  FreqInt: Int64;

begin
  FreqInt := BytesToInt64(AData,23);
  LabelFreq.Caption := IntToStr(FreqInt);
end;
```

Here is the data on the wire in hex notation, starting at position 23:

> 00 00 00 00 00 6b f0 d0

Which represents a freq of 7074000 hz.

My code above is resulting in a freq value of 58811137507983360.

I have also confirmed the hex data by reading each byte with the `Ord()` function on a string representing the frequency.

```
FreqStr := BytesToString(Adata,23,8);
Int8 := Ord(FreqStr[8]);
```

Int8 is now = 208 - the correct value for 0xd0.  Did same for bytes 5, 6, & 7.  Confirmed.

So I know I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are not taking endian into account.

Decimal `7074000` is hex `0x6BF0D0`. Decimal `58811137507983360` is hex `0xD0F06B00000000`. See the similarity? Their bytes are in opposite order.

The bytes in your packet are in network byte order (big endian) but your machine uses little endian instead. You need to swap the bytes of the `Int64`. You can use Indy's `GStack.NetworkToHost()` method for that:

```pascal
procedure TWSJTxUDPClient.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  FreqInt: Int64;
begin
  FreqInt := BytesToInt64(AData, 23);
  FreqInt := Int64(GStack.NetworkToHost(UInt64(FreqInt)));
  LabelFreq.Caption := IntToStr(FreqInt);
end;
```

Comment: I figured it was something like Endian.  Whew.  Thanks much.  Have added that one line of code and now I am getting the expected results. That worked great!  
Thanks much for your help!